# Is it correct to write 'spend too much time on social media' or do I have to say 'on social networking websites'?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Is it correct to write '**spend too much time on social media**'（not sure about the preposition) or do I have to say '**on social networking websites**'?

When I'm not sure whether it is correct to write something I google it, I googled 'spend time on social media' but looks like no one writes like that.

I wish to write the former because I think social media covers a wider range than the latter, such as some Apps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

'Social media' has become a generally acceptable and widespread understood term, so you are fine to use this without looking like a dummy.

While 'social network sites' has a more formal tone, recently I have been seeing the term 'social media' also more and more in formal reports, so also in this setting I would deem that acceptable.

Comment: Thank you, Rick. But is it correct to write 'people spend too much time on social media' in an essay?

Comment: @EmmaXL I have seen the term 'social media' in multiple peer reviewed papers already, so I would say yes.